# Rails 3 + devise - login at specific subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, subdomain

I have Rails 3.2 app with Devise gem and i18n. But i would like to improve a little my application and allow users to login at such subdomain: `login.my-address.com`. But i can't figure how to do that. I understand that i should point somehow to `devise/sessions#new` and i tried few things which didn't help me. Did anyone create such solutions?

My routes:

```
  scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do    
    resources :articles
    resources :photos
    ...

    root :to => 'articles#index'
  end

  match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}"), constraints: lambda { |req| !req.path.starts_with? "/#{I18n.default_locale}/" } # i18n.
  match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/articles")                              # Redirect by default to articles.
```